# How to fire click event in moxie highcharts

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I want to show popup on a point when user mouse over on point in series in highcharts. I got clientx value 0 when I move the cursor on a point  but when I click on a point I get correct client x and client y values. I am unable to find the solution for this. I there any way to do this? or I need to fire click event when I hover over a point to get correct client x and client y coordinates. I am using gwt .

Thanks

Comment: If you're setting the handler via SeriesPlotOptions.setSeriesMouseOverEventHandler(..) try to enable mouse tracking with .setEnableMouseTracking() it may affect the coordinates you get

Answer (score 0):

Write your function in

```
  point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {}
                    }
                    }
```

refer [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/nomewwpf/)

Comment: Plz check fiddle in my answer